# A right angle triangle of that symbol with sides equal to that number

Tags: c

The program I'm working on outputs a right triangle of that symbol with sides equal to that number. What it should do is terminate if you enter 0 otherwise it should ask for a new input again.

So my question is how can I make it terminate if you enter 0, otherwise ask for another input? I know I probably need to use while loop. But how do I change it?

Here is my code:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char s;         /*s is symbol (the input)*/
    int a, b, n;    /*n is number of rows (the input)*/

    printf("Please type the symbol of the triangle:...\n"); /*Ask for symbol input*/
    scanf_s("%c", &s, 1);
    printf("Please type a positive non-zero number between 5 and 35:...\n"); /*Ask for number of rows input*/
    scanf_s("%d", &n);
    assert(n >= 5 && n <= 35);

    for (a = 1; a <= n; a++) /*How many rows to display+create*/
    {
        for (b = 1; b <= a; b++)
        {
            printf("%c", s);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: So my question is that "HOW to terminates if you enter 0 otherwise it will ask for a new input again. "
I know I probably need to use while loop. But how do i change it?

Comment: Do not ask questions in the comments. Instead, include it in your actual question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use loops to do that.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifndef _MSC_VER
/* passing extra arguments to scanf is not harmful */
#define scanf_s scanf
#endif

int main(void)
{
    char s;         /*s is symbol (the input)*/
    int a, b, n;    /*n is number of rows (the input)*/

    do {
        printf("Please type the symbol of the triangle:...\n"); /*Ask for symbol     input*/
        scanf_s("%c", &s, 1);
        printf("Please type a positive non-zero number between 5 and 35:...\n");     /*Ask for number of rows input*/
        scanf_s("%d", &n);
        if(n >= 5 && n <= 35)
        {
            for (a = 1; a <= n; a++)/*How many rows to display+create*/
            {
                for (b = 1; b <= a; b++)
                {
                    printf("%c", s);
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
        while ((a = getchar()) != '\n' && a != EOF); /* remove the newline character from standard input buffer */
    } while (n != 0);
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: Thanks!

We haven't learned about " while ((a = getchar()) != '\n' && a != EOF); /* remove the newline character from standard input buffer */"

is there any "simple" way to say that?

Comment: @EricYeh I think this is a simple way. Please define "simple".

Comment: Because we haven't learned about getchar and EOF as a beginner, so i am wondering if there is another way to do that.

Comment: If you don't have to accept whitespace characters for building the triangle, you can add a space before `%c` in the format specifier to have `scanf()` ignore whitespaces.